# Charting multivariables in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have data in the following format in Splunk:

```
AppName  time count
app1     00.00 110
         00.10 120
         00.30 130
app2     00.00 210
         00.10 220
         00.30 230
```

How do I plot the above as a overlaid time series chart?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain how Splunk separated events and time on this data?
All these lines appear in 1 event? or each line is an event?

Assuming second answer:

```
|timechart avg(count) by AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to chart them in overlaid, time series:

`index=* |timechart values(count) by AppName`

code above should do the trick